# Urllib Counts as WebPage Hit?

Tags: python, google-chrome, urllib

I'm studying opening pages through Python (3.3).

```
 url=('http://www.google.com')
 page = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
```

Does the above code count that as one hit to Google or does this?

`os.system('start chrome.exe google.com')`

The first one scrapes the page while the second one actually opens the page in a browser. I was just wondering if it made a difference page hit wise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

both do very different things.

using `urllib.request.urlopen` makes a single http request.

your second example will do the same, and *then* it will parse the document it receives and request subsequent resources (images/javascript/css/whatever).  So the result of loading google.com in your browser will trigger many hits.

try it yourself by looking in your browsers development tools (usually in network section) while you load a page.

Comment: Ok just so I'm getting this. The `urllib` makes 1 hit while the other makes multiple?